# Python: Find and replace function call

Tags: python, replace

I want to delete all occurrences of the text `foo(param1, param2)` in a file, using python.

`param1` and `param2` are just examples, it may very between occurrences.

Notice: `param1` and `param2` may contain brackets.

Comment: Can your `param1` or `param2` contain pairs of parentheses? E.g. `foo((1 + 2), bar())`? If so, neither simple text substitution nor regexps are going to help you. Search for `foo(` and scan for the closing paren, using a stack to keep the balance of open/closed parens.

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` doesn't have multiple signatures, a simple regex might work. Take a look at the `re.sub` method.

For example:

```
re.sub('foo\(.+,.+\)', '', line)
```

will delete the following occurrences (including calls to foo that contain bad syntax):

```
foo(a, b)
foo([a], b)
foo([a b c], d)   # note, bad syntax
```

Comment: Thanks. What about  `foo(bar(num1, num2), param2)`?

Comment: @Subway yes, that will also be matched.

Comment: in case of `foo(bar(num1, num2), param2)`, only `foo(bar(num1, num2)` will be deleted.

Comment: That's strange - it works for me in the Python 2.7.6 console:

`>>> re.sub('foo\(.+,.+\)', '', 'foo(bar(num1, num2), param2)')`
`''`

Answer (score 0):

Control+h is find and replace on windows. Pretty sure this works in idle